# Echo variable from query string?

Tags: php, query-string

I've just made a 404 system that functions in two ways:
?404 - Will load a random meme.
?404=(a-u) - will specify a meme.

Currently I have to specify all of them in the selector part, is there a way get query string and echo variable from that?

```
<center>
    <br>
    <?php
        $a = '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAxQ9Bd_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">';
        $b = '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aPjmGrB_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">';
        $c = '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a2oMpY1_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">';
        $d = '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/anM7Djq_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">';
        $e = '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/awrmNLB_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">';
        $f = '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aMAvmGM_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">';
        $g = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/avOWw3Z_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/avOWw3Z_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/avOWw3Z_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/avOWw3Z_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $h = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0Kognd_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0Kognd_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0Kognd_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0Kognd_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $i = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/agXQ9Wq_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/agXQ9Wq_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/agXQ9Wq_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/agXQ9Wq_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $j = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAxQ232_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAxQ232_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAxQ232_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAxQ232_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $k = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/anMOZZo_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/anMOZZo_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/anMOZZo_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/anMOZZo_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $l = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aExMKDn_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aExMKDn_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aExMKDn_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aExMKDn_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $m = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAxQAPZ_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAxQAPZ_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAxQAPZ_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAxQAPZ_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $n = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aZ3n9zz_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aZ3n9zz_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aZ3n9zz_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aZ3n9zz_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $o = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/agXQRo6_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/agXQRo6_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/agXQRo6_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/agXQRo6_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $p = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0KXb7Q_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0KXb7Q_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0KXb7Q_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0KXb7Q_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $r = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aLjz2LV_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aLjz2LV_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aLjz2LV_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aLjz2LV_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $r = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0KXYvZ_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0KXYvZ_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0KXYvZ_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a0KXYvZ_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $s = '<video preload="auto" poster="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/arg34Yd_460swp.webp" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/arg34Yd_460svvp9.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/arg34Yd_460sv.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/arg34Yd_460svwm.webm" type="video/webm"></video>';
        $t = '<iframe height="500" width="890" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a3nPG9JpoLg?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay encrypted-media"></iframe> ';
         if ($_GET['404'] == 'a') { echo $a; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'b') { echo $b; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'c') { echo $c; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'd') { echo $d; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'e') { echo $e; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'f') { echo $f; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'g') { echo $g; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'h') { echo $h; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'i') { echo $i; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'j') { echo $j; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'k') { echo $k; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'k') { echo $l; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'm') { echo $m; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'n') { echo $n; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'o') { echo $o; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'p') { echo $p; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'q') { echo $q; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 'r') { echo $r; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 's') { echo $s; }
    else if ($_GET['404'] == 't') { echo $t; }
    else {
        $error = range('a', 't');
        $random_error = array_rand($error);
        echo $$error[$random_error];
    }
    ?>
    <h1>You dun goofed</h1>
    <?php echo 'Error code: '. $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>
</center>
<style>
    body { overflow-y: hidden; }
    #content { height: 1000px; }
</style>
```

Comment: Please try and keep your questions self-contained. Off-site links are strongly discouraged because they're inconvenient, might be firewalled for some people, and may change or get deleted later.

Comment: I'd also recommend you learn about PHP's associative arrays because this sort of style of programming is not sustainable. With an associative array you can do `$message[$_GET['404']]` instead of needing *N* `if` statements.

Comment: Its a flipping 58 lines, wouldnt pasting it in there be considered spam or something?

Comment: The trick is to post just *enough* lines that we know what you're talking about. Like post `a,b...y,z` and we can understand there's other stuff snipped for brevity. You don't need to exhaustively list all the things. Posting it off-site doesn't help us read all that duplicated code any faster.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of :

```
    $a = '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAxQ9Bd_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">';
    $b = '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aPjmGrB_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">';
    $c = '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a2oMpY1_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">';
```

etc, you could use an associative array, like:

```
$memes = array(
    'a' => '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAxQ9Bd_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">',
    'b' => '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aPjmGrB_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">',
    'c' => '<img src="https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a2oMpY1_460s.jpg" style="max-height: 500px; min-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;">',
 );
```

Then you could use the query string value to get the member based on that key, like:

```
echo $memes[$_GET['404']];
```

Comment: A great first refactoring.

Comment: Could you show me how I'd add this to my code? I have like 3 weeks of experience with PHP, 40% of this code isn't even by me...

Comment: @DoubleThePsycho replace the `if ($_GET['404'] == 'a') { echo $a; }` lines with `if (array_key_exists('404', $_GET) && array_key_exists($GET['404'], $memes)){ echo $memes[$_GET['404']]; } else { //... error }`

Comment: I gave this a try. The rest of the page loaded this time, but the meme itself doesn't appear. My current code:
`'u' => ''
  );
  if (array_key_exists('404', $_GET) && array_key_exists($GET['404'], $memes)){
   echo $memes[$_GET['404']];
  } else {}
 ?>
 <h1>You dun goofed</h1>
 <?php echo $random_error; ?>`

Comment: Changed it to https://3v4l.org/ADOtJ to make item display on random, thanks a lot for the help pal!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [variable-variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
echo $$_GET['404'];
```

although with it being an array you may have to do:

```
echo ${$_GET['404']};
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4f51e957806e803300dd58e892532e311a19a32a

A better solution, though, would be to save the variables in an array:

```
$images = ['a' => 'something.jpg', 'b' => . 'something-else.png'];
echo $images[$_GET['404']];
```

Comment: While technically correct, this just doubles down on the problematic design of this code.